# Liquibase issues with labels and context

Tags: liquibase

We are using LB 3.5. Below is the master changelog

```
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd">


    <!-- v13.0.00 -->
    <include context="v13_0_00_03" file="changelog-v13.0.00.03.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
    <include context="v13_0_00_04" file="changelog-v13.0.00.04.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

Now in changelog-v13.0.00.03.xml we have these changeSets:

```
<databaseChangeLog
xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd">

<changeSet id="CT-39_1" author="auth1" failOnError="false"  runOnChange="false" labels="DDL">
    <sqlFile encoding="utf8" endDelimiter="\nGO" path="../scripts/ddl/ddl.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true" />
</changeSet>

<changeSet id="CT-2" author="auth2"   runOnChange="false" labels="TRIGPROC">
    <preConditions onFail="CONTINUE">
        <changeSetExecuted id="CT-39_1" author="auth1" />
    </preConditions>
    <sqlFile encoding="utf8" endDelimiter="\nGO" path="../scripts/trigprocs/sp_ins1.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
</changeSet>

<changeSet id="CT-18" author="auth3"   runOnChange="false" labels="TRIGPROC">
    <sqlFile encoding="utf8" endDelimiter="\nGO" path="../scripts/trigprocs/sp_ins2.sql"
             relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
</changeSet>

<changeSet id="CT-2228" author="auth4" runOnChange="false" labels="CONFIG">
    <sqlFile encoding="utf8" endDelimiter="\nGO" path="../scripts/config/insert_rec.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
</changeSet>
```

The following command works fine as I expect to see SQL file of v13.0.00.03 and labeled as CONFIG:

```
liquibase --contexts=v13_0_00_03  --labels=CONFIG updateSQL
```

But this command won't work

```
liquibase --contexts=v13_0_00_03  --labels="CONFIG, DDL" updateSQL
```

It only generates SQL for CONFIG and not DDL. I tried "CONFIG or DDL", no luck.

Another issue is that, if I change the 'labels' attribute in changeSets to 'context', LB doesn't generate anything using --contexts="v13_0_00_03, CONFIG".

Are these bugs or have I missed anything here?

Answer (score 1):

The only possibility that I can think of is that the DDL changes have already been applied. You have the changeset that is labeled DDL as `runOnChange=false`, so even if the file has changed it will not re-run.

Comment: All my changeSets are set as runOnChange=false plus I have removed all the entries in DATABASECHANGELOG before running this. I suspect LB get confused when we have master changelog with <include context='some-context'> and the changesets being included have also been labelled